# jquery ajax post success return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I can not get back my data, here is my code. where is the problem? Thanks.

Index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();// post each click value to another page
     $.ajax({
         url: "post.php", 
         dataType: "html",
         type: 'POST', //I want a type as POST
         data: "name="+value, 
         success: function(data){ 
            $("#result").data($data); 
         }
      });
    });
});
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
<a href="#" class="click">tim</a>
<a href="#" class="click">tom</a>
<a href="#" class="click">jimmy</a>
```

post.php

```
<?php
$name=trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars(rawurldecode($_POST["name"]))));
$data .='Your name is '.$name;
$data .='how do you do';
echo $data;// how to return all the html in post.php? or return $data part? 
?>
```

Comment: It's not the problem (@Tatu has already flagged that up for you), but separately: You *will* have trouble at some point if you don't properly encode your data. You need to call `encodeURIComponent` on your `value` variable: `data: "name="+encodeURIComponent(value)` When you pass a string in for the `data` parameter, **you** are taking responsibility for it being encoded. (Alternately, let jQuery handle it: `data: {name: value}`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the problem?

```
...
success: function(data){ 
    $("#result").data($data); 
}
...
```

You take the data as `data` but try to access it as `$data`, which is a different, uninitialized variable.

Also, you cannot use `.val()` on an `a` element, use `.html()` instead to get the inner HTML. You probably want to use `.html()` instead of `.data()` on `#result` also.

Otherwise your example seems all right.

Answer (score 5):

it should be:

```
success: function(data) {

    $("#result").html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've got an extra dollar sign on the `$data` variable, should be:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#result").data(data);
}
```