# Login Using PHP and AJAX : Not working. Receiving Failed Alert Incorrect Credentials - However Not getting any errors

Tags: php, ajax

I am attempting to establish a successful login, create a logged in session `'$_SESSION['user_id']'` and upon a successful login: I want to redirect the user to their dashboard.php page with their unique user_id parameter.

I.E. `'dashboard.php?id=1'` - Although I'm not exactly sure how to pass the unique user ID parameter in the URL (via the ajax method) so could use some assistance with this too please.

Otherwise, if the login is not successful I want the user to receive an alert stating that the credentials were invalid.

The Problem: I am constantly receiving invalid credentials alert but seeing no errors.

I know it's not the most secure method, however for testing purposes, I am storing my password in my table as MD5 encryption.

Here is my HTML Form:

```
<form action="assets/secure_login.php" method="post" id="loginform"> 

<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" class="login_input" required>   

<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" class="login_input" required>  

<button type="submit" class="login_button" id="login_button">Login</button>   

</form>
```

My AJAX:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'assets/secure_login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
          if (data === 'Login') {
            window.location = 'dashboard.php?id='+(not sure what to put here to generate unique user ID);
          }
          else {
            alert('Invalid Credentials');
          }
       }
   });
 });
});
</script>
```

Here is my connect.php file containing Database Connection:

```
<?php
   $dbhost = 'localhost';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   $dbname = 'myDatabase';
   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
   } ?>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
 include "connect.php";
 class Users {
 public $username = null;
 public $password = null;

 public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
     if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes(        strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
     if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
 }

 public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
    $this->__construct( $params ); 
 }

 public function Login() {
     $success = false;
     try{
        $con = new PDO(include 'connect.php');  
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
                    $user = username;

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindValue( "password", md5($this->password), PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        if( $valid ) {
        $success = true;
                    session_start();


        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user['user'];
        session_write_close();
        echo ('Login');
        exit();

        }

        $con = null;
        return $success;
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return $success;
     }

 } }
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong or help me adjust the code to get it to work correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically the problem is, that's just random chunks of code barely related to each other. I would strongly suggest to lay off AJAX and OOP for a while and use a regular HTML form that is processed by a simple regular procedural PHP script.

Comment: This should be a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007458/jquery-ajax-post-success-return-data. As YourCommonSense stated, rather go with regular procedures. You can find a fully explained method here that covers security, uses PDO prepared statements and the like - https://www.skillshare.com/classes/PHP-Projects-How-to-Create-a-Secure-Session-Based-Login-Script/541658337

Answer (score 0):

If the login in PHP code is successful, you can return data as JSON.
You will redirect with your user ID in your javascript code.

Example :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.json-encode.php

https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.json-decode.php